# Error accessing JSON object in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this Swift code:

```
func getData(completion: (array: Array<AnyObject>)->Void) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://coinabul.com/api.php"))

    let task: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if !error {
            let httpResp: NSHTTPURLResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
            if httpResp.statusCode == 200 {
                var json: NSDictionary = self.convertDataToJSON(data)
                var myArray: Array = Array<Currency>()

                for (key: AnyObject, object: AnyObject) in json {
                    let info: NSDictionary = object as NSDictionary

                    let grams: CGFloat = info["Grams"] as CGFloat
                    let ounces: CGFloat = info["Ounces"] as CGFloat
                    let usd: CGFloat = info["USD"] as CGFloat

                    // Do something with those values
                }
            }
        }
        })

    task.resume()
}

func convertDataToJSON(data: NSData) -> NSDictionary {
    var error: NSError?
    var jsonDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

    return jsonDictionary
}
```

The "json" NSDictionary is correct. If I print it:

```
{
    BTC =     {
        Grams = "15.398340412292";
        Ounces = "0.49506814017307";
        SilverGrams = "1010.0959168583";
        SilverOunces = "32.475337832916";
        USD = "624.825500000000";
    };
    Gold =     {
        Grams = "0.06494206341493";
        Ounces = "2.0199239627704";
        USD = "1262.100000000000";
    };
    Silver =     {
        Grams = "0.0009900049917623401";
        Ounces = "0.030792597293164";
        USD = "19.240000000000";
    };
}
```

I can do `json["Silver"]` and get the corresponding object. But if I try to do `json["Silver"]["USD"]` my app crashes.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
json["Silver"]
```

returns `AnyObject?` which doesn't allow [] because it's unknown what it is, so you have to typecast it for further reference.  Note that Xcode will currently crash if you try to do this in a workspace

```
json["Silver"] as? Dictionary
```

You can string it all together using optional chaining, as:

```
(json["Silver"] as? NSDictionary)?["USD"]
```

Note that the result of indexing operations are almost always optionals, and optional chaining means this one is definitely going to be optional, so you'll have to deal with checking and unwrapping.